# 8 - Firefox loads JS before CSS, causing flash of unstyled content

Tags: javascript, theming, 8

My Drupal 8 site will load fine in Chrome and IE, because they both load my CSS before my JS when I look at the Network tab in the console. But when on Firefox, it will load the JS before the CSS. This causes some crazy flashes of styling as things are being loaded backwards to what should be expected to happen...

Has any one else run into a similar issue and found a workaround or know how I could get Firefox to load my CSS before my JS?

Comment: Recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271276/is-the-recommendation-to-include-css-before-javascript-invalid

Comment: Then you have bad JS because you are executing it immediately when its loaded instead of waiting for dom to be fully build. Check Drupal.behaviors or jquery.ready(deprecated I think).

Comment: For those stumbling into this there is a related core issue as well: https://www.drupal.org/node/2900908